# Real and imaginary part of $f(z) = \frac1{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find the real and imaginary part of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+1}$

$$
f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2+1}
$$
$$
f(z)= \frac{1}{(x^2-y^2+1)+i(2xy)}
$$

What should i do next? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Try to make the denominator real.

Comment: In general, how would you find the real and imaginary part of $\frac1{a+bi}?$

Comment: Why would you write in the title $1/(z^2)+1$ when you clearly mean $1/(z^2+1)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the expression by the complex conjugate of the denominator to make it real. This makes
$$ f(z)=\frac{(x^2-y^2+1)-i(2xy)}{(x^2-y^2+1)^2+(2xy)^2}.$$
Therefore, the real part is
$$\mathfrak{Re}(f(z))=\frac{x^2-y^2+1}{(x^2-y^2+1)^2+(2xy)^2}$$
and the imaginary part is
$$\mathfrak{Im}(f(z))=\frac{-2xy}{(x^2-y^2+1)^2+(2xy)^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Or, in polar form with $\,z = r(\cos\varphi + i \sin\varphi)\,$:

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2+1} \cdot \frac{\bar z^2 + 1}{\bar z^2+1} = \frac{\bar z^2 + 1}{|z|^4+1+2\operatorname{Re}(z^2)} = \frac{r^2 \cos 2\varphi + 1 \;+\; i\, r^2 \sin 2\varphi}{r^2 (r^2 + 2\cos 2\varphi) + 1}
$$